# Get the sum of like values in one column for each value in another column

Tags: php, mysql

ok, I have a mysql table named "sales_records" like so:

```
  User    saleType
+-------+-------+------+
| Jeff  | Sale_Closed  |
+-------+-------+------+
| Jeff  | Sale_null    |
+-------+-------+------+
| Sean  | sale_closed  |
+-------+-------+------+
| Jeff  | sale_closed  |
+-------+-------+------+
| Sean  | sale_closed  |
+-------+-------+------+
| Mark  | Sale_null    |
+-------+-------+------+
| Mark  | sale_closed  |
+-------+-------+------+
| Josh  | sale_closed  |
+-------+-------+------+
| Josh  | sale_closed  |
+-------+-------+------+
```

I'm trying to count up each saleType for each User..  In other words..  Jeff has 2 "sale_closed" and 1 "sale_null. Mark has 1 "sale_closed" and 1 "sale_null", and so on..

and store it into an array.. (Json) like so.:

```
{"jeff":{"sale_closed":2,"sale_null":1},"sean":{"sale_closed":2},"Mark":{"sale_closed":1, "sale_null":1},"Josh":{"sale_closed":2}
```

Ok, so here's my attempt:

```
<?php
// assuming database connection has already been established..

$result = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT `USER' FROM `sales_records`");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $user_array[] = $row['User']; 
}

foreach ($user_array as $user) {
    $json_array[$user] = mysql_query("SELECT saleType FROM sales_records WHERE user='$user'");

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($json_array[$user])) { // AND HERE IS WHERE i GET STUCK!!!
        $json_array[$user][$username][] = $row['saleType']; // I DON'T KNOW WHERE TO GO FROM HERE...
    }
} // AM I APPROACHING THIS CORRECTLY?..

//...
// Once I have all the 'saleType's for each user, maybe I could use:
array_count_values()... or something.

?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get all the data you need in a single query:

```
SELECT user, saleType, count(*) totalSales FROM sales_record
GROUP BY user, saleType
```

That will return all the results in 3 columns that should be easy to turn into JSon.

Comment: Omg!!  haha! And I was working so hard at this!!  Thank you!  Looks like i better increase and practice my Mysql skills..  Awesome thx!  :)